# Unable to connect to gcp using ssh from command terminal (windows machine)

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, ssh

Initially ran the below command in terminal.

gcloud compute ssh --project="pret-registry" --zone="us-east1-b" "pretlist-hw-server" --tunnel-through-iap --dry-run

Output of the above command

ssh -t -i C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\google_compute_engine -o CheckHostIP=no -o HashKnownHosts=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.1900385377936815063 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\google_compute_known_hosts -o "ProxyCommand C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe -S "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\gcloud.py" compute start-iap-tunnel pretlist-hw-server %p --listen-on-stdin --project=pret-registry --zone=us-east1-b --verbosity=warning" aravindh_swaminathan_pretlist_co@compute.1900385377936815063

Tried running the above command in my terminal and got the below error.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

If I navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK in my terminal and run the below command (replaced the aforementioned path with "."), then the connection goes through.

ssh -t -i C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\google_compute_engine -o CheckHostIP=no -o HashKnownHosts=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.1900385377936815063 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\google_compute_known_hosts -o "ProxyCommand .\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe -S ".\google-cloud-sdk\lib\gcloud.py" compute start-iap-tunnel pretlist-hw-server %p --listen-on-stdin --project=pret-registry --zone=us-east1-b --verbosity=warning" aravindh_swaminathan_pretlist_co@compute.1900385377936815063

Need this ssh to work with full path since I want to connect to gcp from vs code.

Comment: This path is incorrect `C:\Users\Administrator.ssh\google_compute_engine`. You are missing a path separator in front of `.ssh`.

Comment: The SSH private key is `C:\Users\Administrator\.ssh\google_compute_engine`. You can then use any SSH client to connect to Compute Engine. I recommend dropping all of the other options such as host checking etc while debugging commands. I use Bitvise which has excellent Windows interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that some double quotes are missing around paths with whitespaces. The actual error is `can't open file 'C:\Program': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`, so I think that you need to *enclose the path in quotes*:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\python.exe"